# How does WIX know if it's installing 32 or 64 Bit software?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, 32bit-64bit, wix3.7

I have a WIX installer that creates some registry keys and installs some software. I do not use the [package](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html)-elements attribute "Platform" and I also do not use the `-arch` switch of `candle.exe`.

I figured out why it copies the software to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor\Product` instead of `C:\Program Files\Vendor\Product`: Apparently, the use of `ProgramFilesFolder` automatically redirects to the 32-bit software path:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder"> <!-- 64 Bit Folder would be "ProgramFiles64Folder" -->
        <Directory Id="Vendor" Name="Vendor">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Product">
```

But I cannot find something similar for registry keys.
Why does WIX redirect registry keys from `Software\Vendor\Product` to `Software\WOW6432Node\Vendor\Product`?
Why does WIX think I install 32 bit software when I don't?

Example: This code creates registry keys in `Software\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\...`

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
    Key="Software\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\$(var.serviceName)\Parameters"
    ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
    <RegistryValue Key="Java" Name="Classpath" Type="string" Value="[JettyHomeDirectory]start.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 (32bit) is the default if  the Platform attribute and -arch switches are omitted.   Once the MSI is compiled it'll use 32bit locations regardless of what your files were compiled as.  It doesn't know what's in your files.

I don't do candle/light from the commandline, I use Visual Studio integration (Votive) / MSBuild.  In that case the solution configuration manager and it's solution/project platforms of x86 (default) and x64  drive the -arch switch automatically.

Because .NET apps will JIT any CPU regardless of where it is installed to, I rarely create x64 specific installers so for the most part I ignore this.  Occassionally, I'll need to install and/or register an unmanaged component to the SystemFolder and then I care.

You need to either 1)  do like I do in visual studio 2) pass -arch property during your build  or 3) set the Package attribute to x64 and ignore the 'this is discouraged' comment.

Comment: I did not know x86 was default and I did not see any differences when I gave `x64` as the `platform` attribute into the `package` element, not sure why. But giving `-arch x64` to the `candle.exe` on command line works. Thanks!

Comment: I only use Votive so perhaps the msbuild targets are picking up on the Platform attribute and using it to pass  -arch to candle.  I am aware of candle and light and what not and many people prefer to do it this way.  Give them visual studio code and a command prompt and they are happy.    Personally I prefer the VS / Votive / MSBuild route and have created an open source project that has substantially more complete project templates and graphical designers.  Only about 1% of my WiX XML is hand edited and I only spend time at the command line when I need to use heat to harvest some COM meta.